# Perl regex missing trailing parentheses on some, but not all records?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my @info = `net view printserver2`;
foreach my $printer (@info)
{
$printer =~ /.+\s+Print\s+\((.+)\)/;
print "$1\n";
```

gives me:

```
16-83
16-84) HP DesignJet 755CM(C3198A
16-84b
16-85
16-SW
17-80
18-45) HP DesignJet 250C (D/A1
18-51) HP DesignJet 650C(C2859B
```

This is the original:

```
(16-83) HP Designjet 800 42 by HP                              
(16-84) HP DesignJet 755CM(C3198A)by HP                        
(16-84b) HP LaserJet 5100 Series PCL6                          
(16-85) HP Designjet T1100ps 44in HPGL2                        
(16-SW) HP LaserJet 4100 Series PCL6                           
(17-80) HP Color LaserJet 5500 PCL 6                           
(18-45) HP DesignJet 250C (D/A1) by HP                         
(18-51) HP DesignJet 650C(C2859B) by HP
```

What is wrong with my regular expression?

This is the result I want:

```
16-83
16-84
16-84b
16-85
16-SW
17-80
18-45
18-51
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is matching up to the *last* ")" on the line. You need to specify a non-greedy match:

```
$printer =~ /.+\s+Print\s+\((.+?)\)/;
```

The question mark after .+ means to stop at the first opportunity.

Or, even better, specify that no ")" can be matched:

```
$printer =~ /.+\s+Print\s+\(([^)]+)\)/;
```